# Convert string to decimal to always have 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, decimal

I'm trying to convert a string to a decimal to always have 2 decimal places. For example:

- 25.88 -> 25.88
- 25.50 -> 25.50
- 25.00 -> 25.00

But with my code below i'm seeing the following:

- 25.88 -> 25.88
- 25.50 -> 25.5
- 25.00 -> 25

My Code:

```
Decimal.Parse("25.50", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

OR

```
Decimal.Parse("25.00");
```

OR

```
Convert.ToDecimal("25.50");
```

For all I get `25.5`. Is it possible to *not cut off* the excess *zeros*?

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal("25.50").ToString("F2");`

Comment: Why would you want trailing zeros after the comma? It's not making the number any more precise or anything.

Comment: just as you display it as a string, you say that it need 2 decimal places just as @DmitryBychenko said. Decimal is always stored as decimal, trailing zeros are redundant.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That gives me a string, I need a decimal

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I know but its for display and needs to have 2 decimal places as its currency

Comment: Another possibility (for `Decimal` only) is `Convert.ToDecimal("25.50") + 0.00M;`

Comment: String-wise, 25.50 and 25.5 aren't the same. But decimal-wise, 25.50 and 25.5 are exactly the same. Do you need a string or a decimal?

Comment: @Ben Then you need a string, not a decimal

Comment: @Ben Use Dmitry's code at the place where you want to output the value.

Comment: Here I've string s1="9.00" and I want to output as decimal d1=9.00 How I'll do? I'm on C# MVC3 –

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Decimal` is a bit strange type, so, technically, you *can* do a little (and may be a *dirty*) trick:

```
// This trick will do for Decimal (but not, say, Double) 
// notice "+ 0.00M"
Decimal result = Convert.ToDecimal("25.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 0.00M; 

// 25.50 
Console.Write(result);
```

But much better approach is formatting (*representing*) the `Decimal` to 2 digits after the decimal point whenever you want to output it:

```
Decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal("25.50", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// represent Decimal with 2 digits after decimal point
Console.Write(d.ToString("F2"));
```

Comment: Didn't know this was possible, strange

Comment: This is very strange, but you are correct. Do you know how it works?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx "...and a scaling factor used to divide the 96-bit integer and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28..."; so `2550` - integer value and `100` scaling factor

Comment: Thanks to you, this day wasn't wasted. I've learned something new.

Comment: @Ben: could you, please, provide a *counter example* in form of piece of code?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I've run exactly `Decimal result = Convert.ToDecimal("25.50") + 0.00M;` and the output is 25.5. This is in the immediate window. Is it something to do with my cultureInfo?

Comment: You also can't see it in debug, but it shows in Console.Write.

Comment: Here I've string s1="9.00" and I want to output as decimal d1=9.00 How I'll do? I'm on C# MVC3

Comment: `Decimal d1 = Decimal.Parse(s1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 0.00m;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you're getting that issue at all, but if you want to fix it:

`yourNumber.ToString("F2")`
It prints out to 2 decimal points, even if there are more or less decimal pointers.

Tested with:

```
decimal d1 = decimal.Parse("25.50");
decimal d2 = decimal.Parse("25.23");
decimal d3 = decimal.Parse("25.000");
decimal d4 = Decimal.Parse("25.00");

Console.WriteLine(d1 + " " + d2 + " " + d3.ToString("F2") + " " + d4);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output: `25.50 25.23 25.00 25.00`

Comment: Here I've string s1="9.00" and I want to output as decimal d1=9.00 How I'll do? I'm on C# MVC3 –