# Force two decimal places on Decimal data type

Tags: c#, sql, devexpress

I have a DAL on the application I'm working on and the class returns objects with decimal data types. I'm having issues with displaying certain values on the front end of the application as they are currency values. I've seen a few similar questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619121/convert-string-to-decimal-to-always-have-2-decimal-places) that's really similar to my issue but nothing matches a scenario where the data type stays a decimal.

At first the issue was that the values were being rounded, which I resolved in SQL by editing the SP. Now the values are coming through correctly but I don't see an option to force the second decimal place when the value is "18.2" for example, it should show "18.20"

The bigger issue is that the DAL is storing these values in a list and the list is then bound to a DevExpress ASP grid. I've formatted the value using DX and it doesn't have an impact:

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="TotalAmountDue" VisibleIndex="5" Width="10%">
    <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="#,###.##" />
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

What is the best approach here?

Comment: How would that work when the data type isn't a string? The list contains decimal values and the list is bound directly to the grid.

Comment: try `#,0.00` to force at least 1 number and 2 decimals 0.10 or 1.01 or 99.99 or indeed 18.20

Comment: Worked like a charm @DaveBecker are there any risks in using this masking method over "#,###.##"

Comment: I don't think so, I've used it a lot over the years and never had any problems.

Comment: Awesome, well it's working great, so I'll apply to the entire solution. Do want to add that as a formal answer?

Comment: @Daniel done!! Glad it worked!

Comment: @Daniel I forgot to mention rounding (see edit). If you have `0.99991` it will attempt to round to the nearest decimal place so will show as `1.00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have variable length number but want thousand seperators and you want to force at least one number before the decimal seperator and 2 after it, use this:

`#,0.00`

Examples

`.1` becomes `0.10`

`18.2` becomes `18.20`

`99` becomes `99.00`

`1234.1` beomes `1,234.10`

EDIT: forgot to mention about rounding

this will round to the nearest decimal place so `0.99991` will display as `1.00`

Comment: The correct names were decimal separator and thousands separator because they depend on the culture settings ;o)

Comment: did you mean to put the space in? it works though, so `123456789` becomes `123, 456,789.00`

Comment: @DaveBecker SO is international with many cultures -> the edit is for all not just for me ;o)

Comment: It was a figure of speech. Obviously I made my edit for the benefit of the whole community, indeed, the reason I post answers in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try `String.Format`?

It works like this:

```
decimal yourPrice=GetPriceFromDb(); //50.2 for example 

txtYourPrice.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", Math.Round(yourPrice, 2));
```

Results that will be display in `txtYourPrice.Text` will be 50.20

Comment: Thanks for the answer Roxy, the problem with that technique is that I'm not working with individual values, I'm binding a list as a datasource to a Dev Express Grid control so @Dave's answer was more efficient